# Get json response with jquery or ajax or angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, request

Good morning **stackoverflow**,

I try to get json response from an URL
[Click](https://www.infojort.com/axs/search?q=marouani%20zied), as expected i got *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* within GoogleChrome, I switched to FireFox, to avoid this problem and then i got status -1 and data null.

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var URL = "https://www.infojort.com/axs/search?q=marouani%20zied";
        console.log('------------------------');
        $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            dataType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            success:function (data) {
                console.dir(data);
                console.log('yes');
            },
            complete:function () {
                console.log('yes');
            }
        })

        $.ajax({
            dataType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            url: URL,
            success: function (data) {
                console.dir(data);
            }
        });

        $.getJSON(URL, function (data) {
            var items = [];
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                items.push("<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>");
            });

            $("<ul/>", {
                "class": "my-new-list",
                html: items.join("")
            }).appendTo("body");
        });
```

**Notice :**

- I can get the response with postman without problems.
- Content-Type →application/json;charset=utf-8

I need a solution with jquery, ajax or angularjs.
Thanks you all.

Comment: try adding crossDomain:true  with ajax calls

Comment: @Yeou eh, that... doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I said that the URL is public and there's no authentication.I found out that the problem depend on URL itself infojort.com/axs/search?q=marouani%20zied sometimes return json and sometimes return error 401.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems related to the API and not to your JavaScript call itself,
what I mean is that **you are trying to Call to your API from a Cross Origin and it is not allowed by default for security reasons, so you have to enable cross origin in the server in order to make this kind of calls** https://spring.io/understanding/CORS

Look at this, it is a Cross Origin call (Jquery within AngularJS):

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: CTHelper.ApiUrl() + '/token',
  data: {
    grant_type: 'password',
    username: $scope.UserName,
    password: $scope.Password
  },
  success: function (result) {
    alert('OK');
  },
  error: function (result) {
    alert('Error');
  }
});
```

but the **API must allows CORS**, this is a part of the file Startup.Auth.cs

[This example uses AspNet Web Api, C# as Backend]

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) {
  ...
  app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
  ...
}
```

**Microsoft.Owin.Cors can be downloaded as a nuget package.**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I said that the URL is public and there's no authentication.I found out that the problem depend on URL itself https://www.infojort.com/axs/search?q=marouani%20zied 
sometimes return json and sometimes return error 401.

Comment: In any case it is a restriction in the server side, you can ask them if they allow cors